# How can i reload a div every 20000 milisec correctly ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So im trying to get a div with an iframe in it to reload every 20 sec, i have searched a bit on it, got a code to work on local, but when i upload it to the internet, it wont work, WHY ?. Are there something i am missing ? or something i could put into the code with fixed the whole thing ?
Im running it with jQuery / Javascript.

The Div looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.sublimevideo.net/js/hqaz26vv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=" [link to the js doc] "></script>
<div id="forsidetop">
    <iframe id='a5a8cf25' name='a5a8cf25' src='http://pixel.tv/ads/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=5&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' width='728' height='90'><a href='http://pixel.tv/ads/www/delivery/ck.php?n=ae74fd18&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' target='_blank'><img src='http://pixel.tv/ads/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=5&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE&amp;n=ae74fd18' border='0' alt='' /></a></iframe>
</div>
```

And the JS code like this:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
    $('#forsidetop').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).load('forsidetop.html', function() {
            $(this).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
}, 20000); // milliseconds
```

The forsidetop.html (the doc that reloads)

```
<iframe id='a5a8cf25' name='a5a8cf25' src='http://pixel.tv/ads/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=5&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' width='728' height='90'><a href='http://pixel.tv/ads/www/delivery/ck.php?n=ae74fd18&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' target='_blank'><img src='http://pixel.tv/ads/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=5&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE&amp;n=ae74fd18' border='0' alt='' /></a></iframe>
```

Comment: What exactly is happening when you upload it?

Comment: Also are you sure the paths are correct?

Comment: Looks good to me. What is happening? Or what isn't happening?

Comment: My guess is the code is working, it is just loading from the cache.

Comment: Could you provide us the url that you published?

Comment: @henrytran http://www.pixel.tv/author/SIlver/ it is the ad up top that dosnt refresh

Comment: @epascarello can you disable it ?

Comment: @olavisau all the html files for reload are placed the same place as the js do yes im sure the path i correct :)
also it is an ad and when it should reload it should restart from with either the a new ad or the same just restartet

Comment: @chet what isnt happening is that it wont reload the ad to a new one or the same just from start

Comment: Okay did try turn cache off
`$.ajaxSetup ({cache: false});`

Comment: I found that the file **forsidetop.html** was not found (404). Moreover, I also found that you declared many variables named **auto_refresh**

Comment: Yea it is there like 
forsidetop.html 
http://pixel.tv/adsrefresh/forsidetop.html

and therefresher
http://www.pixel.tv/adsrefresh/therefresher.js

Comment: and @henrytran = its like for each post type we have to one for the top,mid,low,widget if it is there :)

Comment: Btw are it better to change the wariables or

Comment: `adforsidetop = setInterval(function () {
    $('#forsidetop').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).load('/adsrefresh/forsidetop.html', function() {
            $(this).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
}, 20000); // milliseconds`
I just tested the right path on your site, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently i should have specified the path a little better even tho it is in the same folder as the script

@Henry Tran did come up in a commend with the specified path and it did work

```
adforsidetop = setInterval(function () {
    $('#forsidetop').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).load('/adsrefresh/forsidetop.html', function() {
            $(this).fadeIn('slow'); 
            });
        });
}, 20000); // milliseconds
```

so THx to him :D